# Calling a function in another function with AngularJS factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS factory that has multiple functions.

I want to call one of the functions inside the other function as shown below:

```
.factory("AppStart", function($cordovaSQLite) {
  return {
    init: function() {
      var res = "hello";
      console.log("in load start up page");  
    },
    create_table: function() { 
      AppStart.init();
    }
  }
});
```

But I get the following error:

> AppStart is not defined.

So how do I call the `init()` function in the `create_table()` function? I have tried just calling `init()`, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Remove AppStart.init() from inside the create_table function, inject AppStart in your controller and call AppStart.init from there

Comment: well i dont hv a controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To accomplish this, I recommend defining your functions with names, and then creating a service object with properties that refer to them, as I did below:

```
.factory("AppStart", function($cordovaSQLite) {
    function init() {
        var res = "hello";
        console.log("in load start up page");  
    }

    function create_table() {
        init();
    }

    return {
        init: init,
        create_table: create_table
     };
});
```