# How to define multiple functions and call one function inside other function in Angular JS Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, angularjs-factory

Can Anyone help me how to create multiple function in **Angular JS Factory**, And I want to access the returned value from one function and process something in another function , I have tried below but didn't succeed

In Below Function I wanted to fetch value in modifyProduct function which we get from getProduct(response.data)

I have referred below Questions but didnt get much understanding

[AngularJS : From a factory, how can I call another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18234442/angularjs-from-a-factory-how-can-i-call-another-function)

[Calling a function in another function with AngularJS factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899582/calling-a-function-in-another-function-with-angularjs-factory)

```
 app.factory('ProductsService', function($http) {
  function getProduct() {
    return $http.get('finalmsodetails.json').then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.data);
      return response.data;
    });
  }

  function modifyProduct() {
    this.getProduct().then(function(value) {
      console.log(value);
    });
  }
  return {
    getProduct: getProduct,
    modifyProduct: modifyProduct
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. Just need to drop `this.`, because you're calling another function that's defined in the local scope, not some method on an object. And i think you probably will want to have modifyProduct return the promise, so that anyone calling this function can tell when it succeeds or fails.

```
function modifyProduct() {
  return getProduct().then(function(value) {
    console.log(value);
  });
}
```

Comment: I have tried this @Nicholas , But no value is printed for value , Not sure why

Comment: Yeah log is priniting for `console.log(response.data);` inside getProduct

Comment: So then it seems the change worked, and modifyProduct is calling getProduct. But it makes no sense that getProduct would resolve its promise, but not forward it along... hmmm...

Comment: But I wanted to access the response.data inside modifyProduct,How can i do that

Comment: From what i see, you have all the necessary code. I don't know why it isn't working for you. Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cyphern/bfec7rme/